# Neo4j-Chinese display garbled

Tags: neo4j

how can I show the chinese,thanks.

This is my csv file.[image]

[image]

How can solve it,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD CSV` [requires](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html#csv-file-format) that the CSV file use UTF-8 character encoding. Your file may be using the wrong encoding.